# javascript chainable nested subclass

Tags: javascript, prototype, prototypal-inheritance

I'm effectively trying to build a chainable object that contains sub objects or other functions.

It should be used like this:

```
val().rules.phone("someValue");
```

So far:

```
var val = function(){
  var validator = function(){
    this.fields = [];
    return this;
  }
  validator.prototype = {
    addField: function(fieldName){
       this.fields.push(fieldName);
       return this;
    },
    rules: {
      phone: function(){
        //RETURNING THIS DOES NOT RETURN THE PARENT SCOPE
        //IT RETURNS SCOPE OF PHONE FUNCTION
        return this;
      }
    }
  }
  return new validator();

}
```

I also tried a circular reference via prototype chaining:

```
var val = function(){
    var validator = function(){
        this.fields = [];

        return this;
    }

    var rules = function(){
        validator.call(this);
    }
    rules.prototype = Object.create(validator.prototype);
    rules.prototype.constructor = rules;
    rules.prototype.phone = function(){
    console.log('hone');   
    }

    validator.prototype = {
        addField: function(fieldName){
            this.fields.push(fieldName);    
            return this;
        },
        rules: new rules()

    }

   return new validator();
}

var z = val().rules;
//no 'addFields' function exists on the validator object in the chain.
console.log(z);
```

**Problems:**

In the first `val().rules.phone()` returns the scope of its function rather then the parent scope.  It should return the validator scope.

In the second example, `val().rules` DOES have validator as parent on its prototype chain, however `addFields` prints undefined, and does not exist in console when tracing the chain.

I know I am over complicating the issue by adding the rules literal.  I could just implement chaining with functions directly placed on the prototype object. This is for my own clarification. Is there any other possible way to implement this with the same style usage?

Comment: What's the problem exactly? Why is the code you've posted not working for you?

Comment: correct. its not i will highlight exactly where

Comment: It seems wrong to make `rules` extend `validator`. Why not just have `rules` be something that's made in the `validator` constructor?

Comment: Not sure if you're open to using a framework to help you with your chaining, but if so you may be interested in Task Runner ~ http://taskrunnerjs.com/

Comment: If you are wondering why the `addField` method does not exist on the `rules` object it's because you created a *new* `validator.prototype` after extending the original one to create `rules`. The `rules` constructor has no connection to that new object.

Comment: I see, I think I assumed the entire chain would be instantiated when a child is for some reason / overlooked that / haven't drank any coffee today.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get an API like the one you want with this:

```
var validator = function(){
    this.fields = [];
    this.rules = new rules(this);
}
validator.prototype = {
    addField: function(fieldName){
        this.fields.push(fieldName);    
        return this;
    }
};

var rules = function(validator) {
  this.validator = validator;
}
rules.prototype = {
  addField: function(fieldName) {
    this.validator.addField(fieldName);
    return this;
  },
  phone: function() {
    console.log("phone");
  }
};

v = new validator();
v.rules.addField("hello");
v.rules.phone();
```

Making `rules` inherit `validator` is semantically and practically problematic. Your `validator.prototype` here:

```
validator.prototype = {
    addField: function(fieldName){
        this.fields.push(fieldName);    
        return this;
    },
    rules: new rules()
}
```

will share the same `rules` object between all `validator` objects, which is probably not what you want. But then if you fixed this, by making a `rules` object in the `validator` constructor, you would have an infinite loop, since the `validator` constructor would call the `rules` constructor, and the `rules` constructor would call the `validator` constructor (since a `rules` *is* a `validator`).

Comment: Your comment also helped me greatly in my static implementation of rules!

Answer (score 1):

```
var val = function(){
    var validator = function(){
        this.fields = [];

        return this;
    }

    var rules = function(){
        if(!this instanceof rules) return new rules();
        validator.call(this);
        return this;
    }
    validator.prototype = {
        addField: function(fieldName){
            this.fields.push(fieldName);    
            return this;
        },
        rules: rules

    }
    rules.prototype = Object.create(validator.prototype);
    rules.prototype.phone = function(){
    console.log('hone');   
    }



   return new validator();
}
```

`z = val().rules` actually returns you an object and not a function. that's why you are unable to use `prototype` for that.

Comment: Guess there is no way to preserve chain-ability (without calling new in API use) without causing infinite recursion.